# Use PHP to maintain format of a textarea

Tags: php, forms, richtextbox

Hy Ho,

It is possible to maintain the format of a text area with a PHP form so that a message that is mail'd to the admin is formatted nicely.

ie. If someone writes in the textarea,

> Dear Sir,
>
> I am writing in connceti....
>
> Many Thanks,

At the moment it emails as

> Dear Sir, I am writing in connceti...
>   Many Thanks,

If not then I suppose the solution is Rich Text Editor replacement textarea. Thats all well and good, but what if javascript is disable.

Any ideas,

Marvellous

Comment: Are you emailing as text or as html? If your email is html, then you need to convert new lines to <br/> tag using ln2br() before putting the text into the email.

Comment: If you only need to keep the proper lines, you can try [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php). You should also take a look @ [sending HTML email](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), since you're bound to need it if you plan on using Rich Text Editor

Comment: Blast, simple answer. I had it set to content type: html.. All fixed

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to replace (depending on system):

```
\n\r   or   \n   or   \r
```

By:

```
<br />
```

PHP function needed:

```
nl2br()
```

Comment: The only problem with this is you would need to manually add "\n" before each line break in order for ln2br() to work. :(

Comment: No, `\n` or `\r` or `\n\r` simply represents the line-break in plain text. Check the explanation by JohnP. No need to insert anything.

Comment: Actually it should be `nl2br()` not `ln2br()`

Answer (score 0):

At this point it seems as though your emails might be sent in HTML format. HTML format automatically removes the line breaks if the given input is not in HTML format. If you don't want HTML formatting then try sending the message plain text, then your line breaks should still show.

To send the message as plain text, simply use the PHP mail() function, without any additional headers:

```
mail('john@gmail.com', 'Test Email', 'My Message...

with a line break!');
```

If you are still having problems, try integrating an HTML WYSIWYG editor, such as the powerful [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com) editor.

Note: for the HTML editor to send emails properly, you *will* need to send emails messages in HTML format (where you would need to supply headers as the fourth parameter in the [mail() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)). This will, for sure, solve your line break issues.

Hope that helps,
spryno724

Answer (score 0):

The newlines in a `<textarea>` are preserved by both the browser and PHP. Probably they get lost in the email body itself or they are simply not being displayed by the browser even if they are there.

If you are sending a HTML mail you need to do `nl2br(htmlspecialchars($your_textarea_data))` to add the necessary `<br>` tags.

If you are sending a plain text mail check if you are mixing LF (Unix-style) and CR+LF (DOS-style) newline sequences that maybe confuse your e-mail client.

Answer (score 0):

This depends purely in your email format.

When you type  that text, it actually looks like this

```
Dear Sir, \n
\n
I am writing in connceti....\n
\n
Many Thanks,
```

If you're sending text mail, you have to make sure the linebreaks are not stripped out. And if you're sending out HTML email, you have to make sure you replace those linebreaks for `<br>` tags